# assigning a value to an object's iVar inside an array

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c-runtime

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    [dataArray addObject:[UITextView new]];
    dataArray[i].text = "here";
                 ^Property 'text' not found on object of type 'id'
}
```

I check the class, methods and iVars... everything is there, but I can't use them.

I want a UIScrollView with a user defined number of data fields (like 'Contants' app).  So I load them into an array and put them onto the scroll view.

However, I can't call the methods.  I want to use some kind of strut (array, dict, etc...)

I tried this:

```
textView1 = dataArray[i];
textView1.text = @"#########   Here I am    ##########";
```

But that doesn't seem to store in the object inside the array.  I thought the array stored a pointer to the object and that textView1 would be a pointer to the object so it should store the value of '.text' to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried seems a bit unclear to me, but this should work:

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    UITextView *t = [UITextView new];
    [dataArray addObject:t];
    t.text = @"here";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to load a list of textField and labels so that I can load them from a data store to a data entry page that scrolls.  I use the array because the number of textFields will change.  The pointer 't' won't be there when it's being processed.  This is like the 'Contacts' app from the iPhone where you have many fields to enter data into.

Comment: oh is your code above only an example?

Comment: well the overall problem is `dataArray[i].text = "here";` since NSArrays only store objects of type NSObject, so going `dataArray[i]` is returning you an NSObject which does not have a .text property. you need to cast dataArray[i] to a UITextField first, then access the .text (which is explained in the duplicate question)

Comment: Ok, I think I see it now.     UITextView *myTextView;
    
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        [dataArray addObject:[UITextView new]];
        myTextView = (UITextView *)[dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
        myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item # %d", i];
        }  // it looks like it is a pointer, I just have to cast it from id to work with it.

Comment: yep that should do it